# Regex match everything except numbers and special characters

Tags: python, regex

For this list, how can I extract everything except for numbers and special characters.

```
Jéssica Andrade 1
Joanna Jędrzejczyk
8 Maurício Rua
Jiří Procházka
(6) Anthony Smith
Volkan Oezdemir
Nikita Krylov
Johnny Walker 9
```

Desired output/matched:

```
Jéssica Andrade
Joanna Jędrzejczyk
Maurício Rua
Jiří Procházka
Anthony Smith
Volkan Oezdemir
Nikita Krylov
Johnny Walker
```

`[a-z A-Z]+` matches english characters only.
`[^\x00-\x7F]+` or `[^\u0000-\u007F]+` matches non-english characters only.

Not sure what to do from here.

Comment: Is this JS, PCRE or some other flavor?

Comment: @vrintle Python.

Comment: This specification will mangle names with apostrophes (such as O'Brien, unless written with the Unicode modifier letter apostrophe, as OʼBrien), those with hyphens, digits, etc. See also: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex (with `i` flag),

```
([a-z\u00C0-\u024F] ?)+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LE28Ha/2)

---

### Explanation

- `[a-z]` - matches any alphabetical character (`i` enabled)

- `[\u00C0-\u024F]` - matches

  - `\u00C0-\u00FF` [Latin-1 Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block))
  - `\u0100-\u017F` [Latin Extended-A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A)
  - `\u0180-\u024F` [Latin Extended-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-B)

- `?` - matches a space 0 or 1 time

Comment: That's specific to the languages written in those character ranges, though; it will discard names in other languages...

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex in `re.sub`:

```
\s*(?:\d|[^\w\s])+\s*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RdEmYL/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\s*`: Matches 0 or more whitespaces
- `(?:\d|[^\w\s])`: Matches a digit or a character that is not a word character and not a whitespace. Match 1 or more of this non-capture group.
- `\s*`: Matches 0 or more whitespaces

**Code:**

```
import re

regex = r"[ \t]*(?:\d|[^\w\s])+[ \t]*"

test_str = ("Jéssica Andrade 1\n"
    "Joanna Jędrzejczyk\n"
    "8 Maurício Rua\n"
    "Jiří Procházka\n"
    "(6) Anthony Smith\n"
    "Volkan Oezdemir\n"
    "Nikita Krylov\n"
    "Johnny Walker 9\n")

result = re.sub(regex, "", test_str, 0, re.UNICODE)
```